# How to prefetch_related in reverse of a Django ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

In Django, if I have a ManyToManyField:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

I can minimize hits on the database when accessing the `Pizza` model's `toppings` field by using [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related):

`Pizza.objects.all().prefetch_related('toppings')`

How can I do the same but in reverse, to prefetch the `pizza_set` from a `Topping` queryset?

This doesn't work, and I couldn't find it in the docs:

`Topping.objects.all().prefetch_related('pizza_set')`

Comment: That should work. Do you get an error or empty queryset or something else?

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you access the prefetched pizzas like this:

```
topping.pizza_set.all()
```

If you do something like

```
topping.pizza_set.filter(...some conditions etc...)
```

then it won't work and this is expected (as only specific query result is prefetched).